# send mute push notification with firebase

Tags: push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send notification at night to the user. I do not want to play any sound, I just want the user to see it on his status bar when he wakes up.

How can I send push notification without playing sound on the user device ( both android and ios)?

Comment: Android or iOS?

Answer (score 3):

**From Firebase Notification web console:**

- you can set `sound = disabled` in the advanced option
- Extra tip: you can also set a delivery type relative to the device: like 8am on the user timezone.

**Using Firebase Cloud Messaging API:**

- you can send a notification-message without sound:
  to do this do not specify any **sound** parameter in the `notification: { title: '' .. }` json
- or you can send a data-message:  `data: {key: value, key2: value2, ..}`
  this message will not trigger any automatic notification, only your app callback. then you add code to create the notification in the way you prefer.

List of parameters for notification-messages:
 https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support

Read more about notification-messages vs data-messages here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options