# How to disable/enable notification sound for your flutter application?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, push-notification

I want to disable sound for incoming notification when the user turn of the notification switch in my app.

I also read official documentation but couldn't find anything helpful.

Is there any way?
Also I added property playsound: false
but it's not working for me, I still got android default notification sound.

I tried [This package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) for local notifications but didn't find what I am looking for!

Refer my code below for sending notification on android.

```
    import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';

class MusicNotification {
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  Future<void> init() async {
    const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
        AndroidInitializationSettings("@mipmap/ic_launcher");

    const DarwinInitializationSettings initializationSettingsIOS =
        DarwinInitializationSettings();

    const InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(
      android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
      iOS: initializationSettingsIOS,
    );

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
      initializationSettings,
    );
  }

  void showNotificationAndroid(String title, String value) async {
    const AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails =
        AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'Music123',
      'Music',
      channelDescription: 'Music Notification',
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.high,
      playSound: false,
      ticker: 'ticker',
    );

    int notification_id = 1;
    const NotificationDetails notificationDetails =
        NotificationDetails(android: androidNotificationDetails);

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        notification_id, title, value, notificationDetails,
        payload: 'Not present');
  }
}
```

and this is for calling notification event

```
MusicNotification().showNotificationAndroid(
    'title',
    'value');
```

Answer (score 2):

This should be handled by your backend service. You can mute the sound by not sending "sound" key in your Cloud Messaging API. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40058682/send-mute-push-notification-with-firebase)

Answer (score 0):

One of the techniques can be deleting your old notification channel with sound and recreating the channel with no sound. [This](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) package is handy for dealing with notifications in flutter.

- [Delete Notification Channel](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_local_notifications/latest/flutter_local_notifications/AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin/deleteNotificationChannel.html)
- [Create Notification Channel](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_local_notifications/latest/flutter_local_notifications/AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin/createNotificationChannel.html)